# Django keeps restarting itself in development mode

Tags: django, reload, restart

Django development server keeps restarting itself, without any differences made to any files under the project directory.

Below is the output:

den@ev:~/calisma/ > python manage.py runserver 9000 -v 2 --traceback 
Validating models...
0 errors found

Django version 1.1.1, using settings 'myproject.settings'
Development server is running at http://127.0.0.1:9000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
Validating models...
0 errors found

Django version 1.1.1, using settings 'myproject.settings'
Development server is running at http://127.0.0.1:9000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
Validating models...
0 errors found

Django version 1.1.1, using settings 'myproject.settings'
Development server is running at http://127.0.0.1:9000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
Validating models...
0 errors found

Django version 1.1.1, using settings 'myproject.settings'
Development server is running at http://127.0.0.1:9000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.

^C

Most probably it does not like something somewhere in the project files
but couldn't get it choke out what's wrong.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 10):

- Delete all the `.pyc` files
- Use `manage.py runserver --noreload`
- Try the same with an empty project. Or just disable all the `INSTALLED_APPS` setting.

How often does it reload? Inmediately, each X seconds, at random?

Comment: done all :) no change. I have other projects as well, running without problems with development server. This project had no problems either when i shut it down. But today, without any changes it just reloads itself periodically in 2 seconds after it boots each time.

Comment: nah.. was hitting file descriptors limit! brute force debugging by decorating everywhere up to basehttpserver with "print 'blah'", showed that nothing was failing. i've shut down some other programs, server is not restarting continuously now. damn you fdlimit!

Answer (score 4):

First ensure that the date of your computer is correctly configured (up to date) if it is not update it then retry to run the server.
If it still does not work I advise you to run the server with the option --noreload while waiting to find the solution but in my case that was exactly the same as the one meant set the date solved my problem.